# Can't join OS X Mavericks to AD Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, mac-osx

I'm attempting to join an OS X Mavericks (10.9) client to a Windows Server 2008 Active Directory domain, however the bind fails with this error in the OS X client's `system.log`:

```
Oct 24 15:03:15 host.domain.com com.apple.preferences.users.remoteservice[5547]: -[ODCAddServerSheetController handleOtherActionError: gotError: Error Domain=com.apple.OpenDirectory Code=5202 "Authentication server encountered an error while attempting the requested operation." UserInfo=0x7f9e6cb3e180 {NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication server encountered an error while attempting the requested operation., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Authentication server encountered an error while attempting the requested operation.}, Authentication server encountered an error while attempting the requested operation.
```

I've joined (bound) Ubuntu Linux clients to the same domain with `net ads join` in the past with no problems (using the same user). I don't have access to any server logs.

Here's the GUI error (from Directory Utility) on the OS X client:
[image: Directory Utility Bind Error]

Here's the GUI error (from User's and Groups) in System Preferences on the OS X client:
[image: User's and Groups Bind Error]

**Directory Services Log**

```
2013-10-25 14:19:13.219128 PDT - 10544.20463 - ODNodeCustomCall request, NodeID: 52A65FAE-4B24-455D-86EC-2199A780D234, Code: 80
2013-10-25 14:19:13.220409 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - client requested OU - 'CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.220427 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Binding using 'user@DOMAIN.COM' for kerberos ID
2013-10-25 14:19:13.220571 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - new kerberos credential cache 'MEMORY:0x7fa713635470' for 'user@DOMAIN.COM'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.220623 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: loop 1
2013-10-25 14:19:13.220639 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - KDC send 0 patypes
2013-10-25 14:19:13.220653 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - fast disabled, not doing any fast wrapping
2013-10-25 14:19:13.220699 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - Trying to find service kdc for realm DOMAIN.COM flags 0
2013-10-25 14:19:13.221275 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - submissing new requests to new host
2013-10-25 14:19:13.221326 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to host: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00000001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.221373 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - writing packet: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00000001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222588 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - reading packet: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00000001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222617 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - host completed: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00000001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222665 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_sendto_context DOMAIN.COM done: 0 hosts 1 packets 1 wc: 0.001960 nr: 0.000000 kh: 0.000560 tid: 00000001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222705 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: loop 2
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222737 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: processing input
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222752 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: got an KRB-ERROR from KDC
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222775 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: KRB-ERROR -1765328359/Additional pre-authentication required
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222791 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - KDC send 4 patypes
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222800 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - KDC send PA-DATA type: 19
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222808 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - KDC send PA-DATA type: 2
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222816 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - KDC send PA-DATA type: 16
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222825 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - KDC send PA-DATA type: 15
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222840 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: using ENC-TS with enctype 18
2013-10-25 14:19:13.222850 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: using default_s2k_func
2013-10-25 14:19:13.227443 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - fast disabled, not doing any fast wrapping
2013-10-25 14:19:13.227502 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - Trying to find service kdc for realm DOMAIN.COM flags 0
2013-10-25 14:19:13.228233 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - submissing new requests to new host
2013-10-25 14:19:13.228320 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to host: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.228374 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - writing packet: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.229930 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - reading packet: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.229957 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - host completed: udp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.229975 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_sendto trying over again (reset): 0
2013-10-25 14:19:13.230023 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - Trying to find service kdc for realm DOMAIN.COM flags 2
2013-10-25 14:19:13.230664 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - submissing new requests to new host
2013-10-25 14:19:13.230726 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to host: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010002
2013-10-25 14:19:13.230818 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to 11: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010002
2013-10-25 14:19:13.231101 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - writing packet: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010002
2013-10-25 14:19:13.232743 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - reading packet: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010002
2013-10-25 14:19:13.232777 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - host completed: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00010002
2013-10-25 14:19:13.232798 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_sendto_context DOMAIN.COM done: 0 hosts 2 packets 2 wc: 0.005316 nr: 0.000000 kh: 0.001339 tid: 00010002
2013-10-25 14:19:13.232856 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: loop 3
2013-10-25 14:19:13.232868 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: processing input
2013-10-25 14:19:13.232900 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: using keyproc
2013-10-25 14:19:13.232910 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: using default_s2k_func
2013-10-25 14:19:13.236487 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: extracting ticket
2013-10-25 14:19:13.236557 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_init_creds: wc: 0.015944
2013-10-25 14:19:13.237022 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - Trying to find service kdc for realm DOMAIN.COM flags 2
2013-10-25 14:19:13.237444 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - submissing new requests to new host
2013-10-25 14:19:13.237482 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to host: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00020001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.237551 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to 11: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00020001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.237900 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - writing packet: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00020001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.238616 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - reading packet: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00020001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.238645 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - host completed: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00020001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.238674 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_sendto_context DOMAIN.COM done: 0 hosts 1 packets 1 wc: 0.001656 nr: 0.000000 kh: 0.000409 tid: 00020001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.238839 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - Trying to find service kdc for realm DOMAIN.COM flags 2
2013-10-25 14:19:13.239302 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - submissing new requests to new host
2013-10-25 14:19:13.239360 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to host: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00030001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.239429 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - connecting to 11: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00030001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.239683 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - writing packet: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00030001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240350 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - reading packet: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00030001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240387 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - host completed: tcp 192.168.0.1:kerberos (192.168.0.1) tid: 00030001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240415 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_sendto_context DOMAIN.COM done: 0 hosts 1 packets 1 wc: 0.001578 nr: 0.000000 kh: 0.000445 tid: 00030001
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240514 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - krb5_credential - krb5_get_credentials_with_flags: DOMAIN.COM wc: 0.003615
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240537 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - valid credentials for user@DOMAIN.COM
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240541 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - switching to cache 'MEMORY:0x7fa713635470'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240545 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - switching GSS to cache 'MEMORY:0x7fa713635470
2013-10-25 14:19:13.240555 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Bind Step 5 - Bind/Join computer to domain - 'domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.241345 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - resolving 'server.domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.241646 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - added socket 12 for host 'server.domain.com:389' address '192.168.0.2' to kqueue list
2013-10-25 14:19:13.241930 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Setting kerberos server for 'Kerberos:DOMAIN.COM' to 'server.domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.241962 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - switching to cache 'MEMORY:0x7fa713635470'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.241969 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - switching GSS to cache 'MEMORY:0x7fa713635470
2013-10-25 14:19:13.242231 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI allow Confidentiality
2013-10-25 14:19:13.242234 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - setting realm 'DOMAIN.COM' for node '/Active Directory/domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.242239 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI allow Integrity (signing)
2013-10-25 14:19:13.242274 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI using hostname 'server.domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.242282 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI using initiator credential 'user@DOMAIN.COM'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.250771 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Authenticate to LDAP using Kerberos credential - 0
2013-10-25 14:19:13.250784 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - verified connectivity to '192.168.0.2' with socket 12
2013-10-25 14:19:13.251513 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - locating site using domain domain.com using CLDAP
2013-10-25 14:19:13.252145 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - using site of 'DOMAINGROUP' from CLDAP
2013-10-25 14:19:13.253626 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - resolving 'server2.domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.253933 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - added socket 13 for host 'server2.domain.com:389' address '192.168.0.1' to kqueue list
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254428 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Setting kerberos server for 'Kerberos:DOMAIN.COM' to 'server2.domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254462 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - switching to cache 'MEMORY:0x7fa713635470'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254468 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - switching GSS to cache 'MEMORY:0x7fa713635470
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254617 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - setting realm 'DOMAIN.COM' for node '/Active Directory/domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254661 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI allow Confidentiality
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254670 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI allow Integrity (signing)
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254689 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI using hostname 'server2.domain.com'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.254695 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - GSSAPI using initiator credential 'user@DOMAIN.COM'
2013-10-25 14:19:13.262092 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Authenticate to LDAP using Kerberos credential - 0
2013-10-25 14:19:13.262108 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - verified connectivity to '192.168.0.1' with socket 13
2013-10-25 14:19:13.262982 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Computer account either already exists or DC is already Read/Write
2013-10-25 14:19:13.264968 PDT - 10544.20463, Node: /Active Directory, Module: ActiveDirectory - Adding record 'cn=spike,CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com' in 'domain.com'
```

The failure point seems to be `Computer account either already exists or DC is already Read/Write`, however, I can search for 'spike' on the Active Directory server using Active Directory Explorer and it's not there. If I do the same search for the Linux and Windows PCs I added previously, I can find them.

**Permissions**

I believe I have permission to add computers to the domain--I suspect this is the case because I've already been able to add a Windows 7 computer and a Linux computer (and I can find them with Active Directory Explorer). Also, I suspect the reason I can add computers is that the domain admins left the "Add workstations to domain" GPO at its [default setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780195%28WS.10%29.aspx) which allows authenticated users to add up to 10 computers (of which I've added 2).

**Conclusion**

I talked to my IT department--they told me that between the time I added the Windows and Linux hosts and the time I attempted to add the OS X host, they changed the Group Policy so that users can no longer add machines to the domain. So it seems the best "answer" is "go talk to your IT folks"--which is in several comments below. Thanks to everyone for being helpful, though! The value in this question and analysis is that it shows the root problem from misleading symptoms on the client side--very useful to all the professionals out there.

Comment: The fact that you don't have access to the server logs implies that you don't have access to the servers, which implies that you're not the administrator of the domain you're trying to join this machine to, which begs the question: Why are you not working with/talking to whomever does administer this domain?

Comment: @joeqwerty - You're very astute. :-) Our CIS department "doesn't support" any client but Windows XP or Windows 7 on Dell computers only. I could ask them for logs, but I probably wouldn't get anywhere. I have been authorized to use this OS X machine on the network as long as I don't require support for it.

Comment: Gotcha. You're allowed to join it to the domain but they won't support it in any way. Hopefully someone here will have some insight, although Mavericks may be too new for anyone to have encountered this problem yet.

Comment: Make sure the date and time on your OS X client is within the time skew threshold of the time on the Domain Controllers, if not, authentication will fail. The threshold is 5 minutes by default, and enforced to prevent KRB replay attacks. If the time on the Domain Controller is 15:56, make sure the clients clock is set between 15:51-16:01.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - Thanks for the time tip--I already made sure that the delta between the OS X client and another Windows client was less than 1 minute (I'm not sure what the threshold on the server is).

Comment: What is the computername of your mac? Is it the default `watkipet's-pc`?

Comment: @MDMoore313 - No, the hostname is "spike"--i.e. Snoopy's brother from Peanuts. Pinging the FQDN of my Mac (spike.domain.com) works from the Mac and other Windows hosts.

Comment: @watkipet okay, do you know if you have *rights* to join computers to the domain?

Comment: You should [change your logging](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4696), if you haven't already, and try again.

Comment: @MDMoore313 - I've already joined a Linux machine ("net ads join") and a Windows 7 machine to the domain--so I'm pretty sure I have rights to join computers to the domain.

Comment: You *did* mention that, my mistake, it's been a long day. Yeah, I'd say enable the most verbose logging you can (see my link above) and update your question with the log so I can have a nice bedtime story.

Comment: When you search AD for the computer account, do you search the root (dc=domain,dc=com) or are you searching a subdirectory (ou=department,dc=domain,dc=com)?

Comment: @MDMoore313 - When I searched for the Linux and Windows machines, I searched at the root of AD tree (dc=domain,dc=com), and it found the machines down the tree in some OUs. Our machines get moved around, so I always search the entire tree.

Comment: Wonderful question, sad that the moderators closed it, despite the fact that is on-topic, and generic enough, I found tens of others online struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Check this, almost identical question I added here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140568/solving-unable-to-add-server-the-plugin-encountered-an-error-processing-reques  --- as opposed to SF, this SE site does not close any question that is above the head of the moderators. From all SE sites, the only one where I observed this aggressive behaviour was SF, and is consistent over the years. I am starting to believe that there is a correlation between being a sysadmin and the this kind of non-constructive behaviour.